# Folium draw polygons with distinct colours

Tags: python, choropleth, folium

I have trouble with my assignment. I have to draw over 100 polygons from the xml file and every of them has to have other color. I don't know how to accomplish it.
First I tried to draw polygons in loop, but eventually all polygons have the same color.

```
colors = []
for x in range(len(gminy)):
    color = np.random.randint(16, 256, size=3)
    color = [str(hex(i))[2:] for i in color]
    color = '#'+''.join(color).upper()
    colors.append(color)
cnt = 0
print(colors)
for x in gminy.iterrows():
    styl = {'fillColor':colors[cnt], 'color':'#000000', 'weight':0.1}
    folium.GeoJson(data=x[1]['geometry'], style_function = lambda y: styl).add_to(m)
    cnt += 1
```

Then I tried to create f`olium.Choropleth` object with bins parameter set to 116 (that's the count of polygons) like this:

```
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=gminy,
    name='idTerytTerc',
    data=gminy_nr,
    columns=['idTerytTerc', 'Liczba'],
    key_on='feature.properties.idTerytTerc',
    fill_color='OrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.1,
    legend_name='Liczba mieszkańców',
    highlight=True,
    bins=116
).add_to(m)  
m
```

But when I did this I get an error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-42d7422910e7> in <module>
----> 1 folium.Choropleth(
      2     geo_data=gminy,
      3     name='idTerytTerc',
      4     data=gminy_nr,
      5     columns=['idTerytTerc', 'Liczba'],

C:\Programy\Anaconda\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1223             # We add the colorscale
   1224             nb_bins = len(bin_edges) - 1
-> 1225             color_range = color_brewer(fill_color, n=nb_bins)
   1226             self.color_scale = StepColormap(
   1227                 color_range,

C:\Programy\Anaconda\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\branca\utilities.py in color_brewer(color_code, n)
    150     if not explicit_scheme:
    151         # Check to make sure that it is not a qualitative scheme.
--> 152         if scheme_info[base_code] == 'Qualitative':
    153             matching_quals = []
    154             for key in schemes:

KeyError: 'OrRd'
```

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: That error says that in the line "fill_color='OrRd'" it doesn't understand what OrRd is referring too. So there is a problem with how you are referencing your colors. Looking at the first section of your code, if all your polygons were color #000000 then I would guess that a general color parameter changes the fill, whereas you meant to set the line_color to #000000.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The first section of code doesn't give any errors just doesn't work properly. That error shows up after the second section. The color I reference  to is from documentation https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html and also this color works properly when I doesn't set bin parametr (but then polygons aren't distinct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt instead of adding the geojsons in a loop try adding them once with a style function which applies a distinct color to each polygon.
Example (assuming `gminy` is a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame):

```
for x in gminy.index:
    color = np.random.randint(16, 256, size=3)
    color = [str(hex(i))[2:] for i in color]
    color = '#'+''.join(color).upper()
    gminy.at[x, 'color'] = color

def style(feature):
        return {
            'fillColor': feature['properties']['color'],
            'color': feature['properties']['color'],
            'weight': 1
        }

folium.GeoJson(data=gminy, style_function=style).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it.